# Xcode does not autocompletes any of the Alamofire method

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, alamofire, swift4.1

After integrating `Alamofire` through `CocoaPods` and importing into my `viewconroller.swift`, I try to write a method. But Xcode 9.4 does not autocompletes any method.

Answer (score 0):

**Try building your project first, then try the autocomplete. If that doesn't work, close Xcode then reopen. It should be fine then.**

You might also want to check [this](https://medium.com/@_achou/one-weird-trick-to-fix-autocomplete-in-xcode-9f19dc856944) out.